# xerces c++ parser not compiling

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, ubuntu-14.04, xerces-c

I have installed xerces-c 3.1.1 on ubuntu 14.04 .IDE - Code Blocks

followed instructions from http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/XML-Xerces-C.html
How to compile this parser.cpp file.When i compile parser code on Code Blocks i get a bunch of errors

also tried to compile manually with g++ still the same errors

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o||In function `_start':|
(.text+0x20)||undefined reference to `main'|
/home/san/Documents/Projects/Entity Resolution/Parsers/Xerces tester/parser.o||In function `GetConfig::GetConfig()':|
parser.cpp|| undeenter code herefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLUni::fgXercescDefaultLocale'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize(char const*, char const*, xercesc_3_1::PanicHandler*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(char const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(char const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(char const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(char const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMemory::operator new(unsigned long)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XercesDOMParser::XercesDOMParser(xercesc_3_1::XMLValidator*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*, xercesc_3_1::XMLGrammarPool*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMemory::operator delete(void*)'|
/home/san/Documents/Projects/Entity Resolution/Parsers/Xerces tester/parser.o||In function `GetConfig::~GetConfig()':|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(unsigned short**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(unsigned short**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(unsigned short**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(unsigned short**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate()'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
/home/san/Documents/Projects/Entity Resolution/Parsers/Xerces tester/parser.o||In function `GetConfig::readConfigFile(std::string&)':|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::setValidationScheme(xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::ValSchemes)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::setDoNamespaces(bool)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::setDoSchema(bool)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::setLoadExternalDTD(bool)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::parse(char const*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::AbstractDOMParser::getDocument()'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::transcode(unsigned short const*, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'|
parser.cpp|| undefined reference to `xercesc_3_1::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_1::MemoryManager*)'|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: How did you run g++? Looks like you're not specifying some object files and/or libraries (for example, the file where `main()` is defined).

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors.

Comment: ' g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -c parser.cpp -DMAIN_TEST -o parser '
when i run this it gives no error but i am not able to execute parser

Comment: if i run ' g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -lxerces-c parser.cpp -DMAIN_TEST -o parser ' then i get the same linker errors

Comment: what has to be given in the -l flag

Comment: sudo g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -l/opt/lib/libxerces-c.a  parser.cpp -DMAIN_TEST -o parser 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/opt/lib/libxerces-c.a
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the command and it worked :

g++ -g -L/opt/lib -I/opt/include parser.cpp -o parser -lxerces-c -DMAIN_TEST

So you can also give a try .